# there is no implicit reference to 'card' convertion from 'card' to IComparable

Tags: c#, icomparable

How do I compare card list? I'm getting this error and I don't know what it means or how to fix it. The error I get:

> the type 'Card' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in generic type or method 'secondClass'. there is no implicit reference to 'Card' convertion from 'Card' to IComparable

```
class Node<T>
{
    public int id;
    public T data;
    public Node<T> next;
}

class GameLinkedList<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> temp;
    private int count = 0;

    public void AddFront(T t)
    {
        count++;
        temp = head;
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>();
        node.data = t;
        node.id = count;
        node.next = temp;
        head = node;
    }
}

class Bundle
{
    //private List<Card> deck1;
    GameLinkedList<Card> deck = new GameLinkedList<Card>();
}

class Card
{     
    private Suit suit;
    private Value value;
    private string cardName;
}
```

Comment: Either implement IComparable on Card (per @MarcoFatica's answer below), or remove that requirement (i.e. delete `where T : IComparable`).

Answer (score 3):

Your `Card` class needs to implement the `IComparable` interface

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx)